# Centos 6.5, Active directory and ldapsearch

Tags: active-directory, centos6, ldap

I need to query the ldap part of an Active Directory DC from CentOS 6.5. ldapsearch allows me to do that, but I have found two bumps in the "ldapsearch" road:

1. ldapsearch wraps long text to several lines. Not good.
2. ldapsearch converts any non ASCII characters to base64. Even worse.

I need these two things to automate a recurrent task.

I have googled for a solution, but I haven't found one yet. Some pages told me about some command line switches that CentOS 6.5's ldapsearch doesn't seem to implement. Is there any way to coerce centos 6.5's ldapsearch to do what I want or I have to look somewhere else? Is there any other alternative to ldapsearch that fills my needs anyone knows of?

Comment: You could use perl-LDAP. You can format the output of that however you want.

Comment: I don't understand perl at all, so I didn't try that way. But thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-o ldif-wrap=no` will take care of the 80 character wrap limit.

Piping your output into `sed -r -e 's/^(.*:): (.*)$/echo -n "\1 "; echo \2 | base64 -d/e'` will decode all base64 encoded results. If you're holding EFS certificates you'll want to modify it to touch just the attributes you want.

Only using sed:

`sed -e 'N; s/\n //; P; D' | sed -r -e 's/^(.*:): (.*)$/echo -n "\1 "; echo \2 | base64 -d/e'`

Comment: CentOS 6.5's ldapsearch apparently doesn't support the "-o ldif-wrap=no" switch. The sed part did the trick though. Thanks

Comment: Added a sed only answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction